# Yield within Set to eliminate in an Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, set, yield

I found the following code [here](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/remove-duplicate-active-record) for eliminating duplicate records in an array:

```
require 'set'

class Array
  def uniq_by
    seen = Set.new
    select{ |x| seen.add?( yield( x ) ) }
  end
end
```

And we can use the code above as follows:

```
@messages = Messages.all.uniq_by { |h| h.body }
```

I would like to know how and what happens when the method is called. Can someone explain the internals of the code above? In the `uniq_by` method, we did not do anything to handle block argument. How is the passed argument handled by `uniq_by` method?

Comment: `Array.uniq` takes a block since [Ruby 1.9.3](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-uniq), so no need for this code (anymore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby, when you are putting `yield` keyword inside any method(say `#bar`), you are explicitly telling `#bar` that, you will be using a block with the method `#bar`. So `yield` knows, inside the method block will be converted to a [`Proc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Proc.html) object, and `yield` have to call that `Proc` object.

Example :

```
def bar
   yield
end

p bar { "hello" } # "hello" 
p bar # bar': no block given (yield) (LocalJumpError)
```

> In the `uniq_by` method, we did not do anything to handle block argument. How is the passed argument handled by `uniq_by` method?

You did do, that is you put `yield`. Once you will put this `yield`, now method is very smart to know, what it supposed to so. In the line `Messages.all.uniq_by { |h| h.body }` you are passing a block `{ |h| h.body }`, and inside the method definition of `uniq_by`, that block has been converted to a `Proc` object, and `yield` does [`Proc#call`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Proc.html#method-i-call).

Proof:

```
def bar
   p block_given? # true
   yield
end

bar { "hello" } # "hello"
```

Better for understanding :

```
class Array
  def uniq_by
    seen = Set.new
    select{ |x| seen.add?( yield( x ) ) }
  end
end
```

*is same as*

```
class Array
  def uniq_by
    seen = Set.new
    # Below you are telling uniq_by, you will be using a block with it
    # by using `yield`.
    select{ |x| var = yield(x); seen.add?(var) }
  end
end
```

Read the doc of [`yield`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-yield)

> Called from inside a method body, yields control to the code block (if any) supplied as part of the method call. If no code block has been supplied, calling `yield` raises an exception. `yield` can take an argument; any values thus yielded are bound to the block's parameters. The value of a call to `yield` is the value of the executed code block.

Comment: But the last argument of that method is select, so if you call uniq_by method without argument what will happen ?

Comment: @pramod **Not argument**, say **without bloc**k..You will get an error ..try now.

Comment: Yes exactly, but is this error because of select or of our yield call ?

Comment: @pramod Not.. `#select`, because `#select` got its **block**, but **uniq_by** didn't get, if you don't call the method without block.

Comment: @pramod when you call yield, a block must have been passed, otherwise you get "no block given (yield) (LocalJumpError)"

Comment: @Arup: If I did that I will get the following error: undefined local variable or method `x'

Comment: @pramod That was my mistake, now I fixed it.

Comment: @pramod Now Just do `select{ |x| seen.add?(x) }`, you will get *local jump* error.

Comment: @Arup: That is my exact question, I run the code without yield and it's working great without any error. Then what is the purpose of yield?

Comment: @pramod Without `yield`, how does your code look like, show it please.

Comment: @pramod I just tried, you should get an error for this.

Comment: @ArupRakshit: I didn't get an error. where can I place my code. If possible please post your code Arup

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47846/discussion-between-arup-rakshit-and-pramod)

Answer (score 3):

Let's break it down :

```
seen = Set.new
```

Create an empty set

```
select{ |x| seen.add?( yield( x ) ) }
```

`Array#select` will keep elements when the block yields true.

`seen.add?(yield(x))` will return true if the result of the block can be added in the set, or false if it can't.

Indeed, `yield(x)` will call the block passed to the `uniq_by` method, and pass `x` as an argument.

In our case, since our block is `{ |h| h.body }`, it would be the same as calling `seen.add?(x.body)`

Since a set is unique, calling `add?` when the element already exists will return false.

So it will try to call `.body` on each element of the array and add it in a set, keeping elements where the adding was possible.

Comment: @pramod it simply evaluates passed block.

Comment: @MarekLipka where the uniq_by method handles the block argument ?

Comment: @pramod by calling "yield". that is what "yield" means: please call the passed block

Comment: @Interpidd: TO handle the block argument we didn't do anything in uniq_by method. So in this case how the bock argument (x) will be handled and  what is the return value of the yield

Comment: @pramod yield will call {|h| h.body}, substituting h for the current x and therefore return x.body

Comment: @MoMolog: I know the how the arguments are handled but my question is after passing an argument to to block what is the return value of that yield and how this happened ?

Comment: @pramod yield will treat the passed block {|h| h.body} like a method, call it with the current x as argument and therefore return x.body. See also my answer.

Comment: @MoMolog: If we create a method and call it with block argument what will happen ?

Comment: @pramod you can always just pass a block. if you never call yield, nothing will happen. see here for more info: http://mudge.name/2011/01/26/passing-blocks-in-ruby-without-block.html

Answer (score 2):

The method `uniq_by` accepts a block argument. This allows to specify, by what criteria you wish to identify two elements as "unique".

The `yield` statement will evaluate the value of the given block for the element and return the value of the elements `body` attribute.
So, if you call `unique_by` like above, you are stating that the attribute `body` of the elements has to be unique for the element to be unique.

To answer the more specific question you have: `yield` will call the passed block `{|h| h.body}` like a method, substituting `h` for the current `x` and therefore return `x.body`

Comment: why are you downvoting this and not give a simple comment? it is a perfectly correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

[`Array#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html) returns a new array containing all elements of the array for which the given block returns a true value.

The block argument of the `select` use [`Set#add?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add-3F) to determine whether the element is already there. `add?` returns `nil` if there is already the same element in the set, otherwise it returns the set itself and add the element to the set.

The block again pass the argument (an element of the array) to another block (the block passed to the `uniq_by`) using `yield`; Return value of the `yield` is return value of the block (`{|h| h.body }`)

The `select ..` statement is basically similar to following statement:

```
select{ |x| seen.add?(x.body) }
```

But by using `yield`, the code avoid hard-coding of `.body`, and defers decision to the block.

Comment: where the uniq_by method handles the block argument ?

Comment: @pramod, An argument of the `yield` (`x`) is passed to the block (`{ |h| ... }`).

Comment: @pramod in `yield(x)`. You evaluate block, passing `x` into it as an argument.

Comment: @pramod yield calls the passed block explicitly with x as the argument